# How to send push notification from web application to android device using Parse?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification

Acually we are done with sending push notion with mobile to mobile.now we are trying to send push notification from web application to mobile devices using javascript.
we tried like this

```
function authentication() {

Parse.$ = jQuery;

  // Initialize Parse with your Parse application javascript keys
  Parse.initialize("app key",
                   "script key");



 var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo("channels","Demo");


  var promise = new Parse.Promise();
debugger;


    Parse.Push.send({
         where: pushQuery,

          data: {
          alert : "Hello word" 

    }}, { success: function() {
          // Push was successful 
          alert : "Push was successful"

        },
          error: function(error) {
         promise.reject(error);

        }}).then (function(error) {
          //Marks this promise as fulfilled, 
          //firing any callbacks waiting on it.


        });

   return promise;
}
```

we getting error like this

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
code: 115
message: "Client-initiated push isn't enabled.
```

We enabled Client Push also
[image]

We are new to Push notification.plz guide us
Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0):

com
step 1 :
1.create your project in parse.com
2.Add parse push notification id in your project.
3.from parse.com your will have send push button to send push notification click and send your message.

fallow this links
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-push-notification-tutorial/
www.parse.com

Comment: we are done with sending push notification from mobile to mobile but now we need to send push notification from web application to mobiles for that we are using javascript in web app .issue is unable to connecet to parse server getting 400(bad request).
where we are going wrong unable understand

Comment: ya first check from parse website to your mobile weather it is working are not based on link which i sent later your update to ur custom code